# AJAX trouble in internet explorer! (code currently works for firefox and chrome)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, dhtml

So I've got an AJAX project which uses the XmlHttpRequest object to dynamically retrieve data from the server-side (in my case, I use JSON with PHP/MySQL in case that's relevant). Pretty much all my HTML elements are created dynamically via the javascript DOM, so it's the .js files doing the work.

Here's a typical .js file I use to get server-side info from PHP and then build the html:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject(); 

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp; 
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } catch(e) {
        var XmlHttpVersions = new Array("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", 
                            "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        for(var i = 0; i < XmlHttpVersions.length && !xmlHttp; i++) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(XmlHttpVersions[i]); 
            } catch(e) {} 
        }
    }
    if (!xmlHttp) alert("Error creating XmlHttpRequest object."); 
    else { return xmlHttp; } 
} 

function initialize_main() {
    if (xmlHttp) {
        try {

            xmlHttp.open("GET", "main_php.php", true); 
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleMainStateChange; //call a function when the state changes
            xmlHttp.send(null); 
        } catch(e) {
            alert("Can't connect to server: " + e.toString());
        } 
    }
}

function handleMainStateChange() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status==200) {  
            try {
                init_main(); 
            } catch(e) {
                alert("Error reading the response: " + e.toString()); 
            }
        } else {
            alert("There was a problem retrieving data: " + xmlHttp.statusText); 
        }
    }
}

function init_main() {

var data = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText); 

//now do stuff with the DOM or w/e 

}
```

So as I said everything is cool in firefox and chrome. But internet explorer tells me: "Error reading the response: TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method". I'm a bit new to AJAX as you might guess, so thanks for any help!

Comment: I will suggest to use [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: I second Tapos; reinventing the wheel (especially when it comes to Javascript, where there is so much cross-browser incompatibility) is crazy.  Use any library to do this, but don't roll your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you use JQuery so that you can write Javascript that doesn't care about the type of browser (JQuery does this for you): http://jquery.com/

Comment: Oh, thanks for the recommendation, and I certainly will for my next project, but I wanted to get down-and-dirty as this was my first exposure to javascript. Unfortunately there's about 10k lines of code written in this fashion that I don't think will be rewritten in jquery... So I'm stuck with (and kinda interested in figuring out) making what I have work with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function, for me it works for all browser

```
function getXMLHTTP()
{
    var xmlhttp = false;
    try
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1)
            {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Comment: hmm, that's odd because I think my version tries both the ActiveXObject combinations you try (plus a few more), yet none of them seem to work for IE. Is there something silly I'm doing/missing in my initial for loop?